# Server Error in '/' Application. Incorrect Syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, syntax-error

Im creating and INSERT form and i got this error, this is my code in codebehind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Selected = category_ddl.SelectedValue;
    lb_date.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    process();
}

private void process()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= |DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    string sql = "INSERT INTO News (date_time,title,author,source,category,description,) VALUES (@date, @title, @author,@source,@Selected,@description)";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lb_date.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title_tb.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", author_tb.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", source_tb.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Selected", category_ddl.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", desc_tb.Text.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

and this is my error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Source Error: 


Line 37:             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Selected", category_ddl.Text.ToString());
Line 38:             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", desc_tb.Text.ToString());
Line 39:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 40:             conn.Close();
Line 41:         }
```

the Line 39:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is highlighted in color red. what did I do something wrong?,i have this using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma after `description`:

> string sql = "INSERT INTO News (date_time,title,author,source,category,description,)

Comment: oh boy! that little comma blown me T.T
i think, I should wear a glassess, thanks man!